# how can i get laravel tymon/jwt-auth refresh token?

Tags: laravel, jwt

i use laravel tymon/jwt-auth for jwt authentication. but when i authenticate, just get access token, not refresh token

in package.json

```
{
...
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "dev-develop"
    }
...
}
```

i expect to get an refresh token to refresh the token after expiration, in the config/jwt.php i can set the expiration time for both access token and refresh token, but i can't get it. how to get the refresh token ?

Answer (score 2):

First, go your project directory 
Open the terminal or CMD inside your project directory and execute the below command

`$ php artisan route:list`

it will give you all the routes regarding your project including the auth routes, inside that route list you can see a route like this

`POST | api/auth/refresh`

you should send the POST request to the above route with by providing the expired access token inside the header or body as Bearer token. It will return the new token as the response.

*Note: if the previous access token is not expired after calling the refresh token, endpoint previous token will be automatically expired.*

Comment: why /api/auth/refresh redirect to login??